# Android Ringtone Setting Error

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ringtone

Click button to run set_ringtone. No error it was setting ringtone. But when I click the button second time, get an error.

```
public void set_ringtone(Context context, String ringtone){
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ringtone + ".mp3");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, ringtone);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST, "Halil Öncen");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC, false);

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
}
```

Logcat,

```
07-30 09:14:34.284 5869-5891/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting _data=/storage/emulated/0/SonyEricssonZilSesi.mp3 title_key=MECY1K9-MMEC[9?M1M9 parent=0 _display_name=SonyEricssonZilSesi.mp3 format=12297 is_music=false is_ringtone=true title=Sony Ericsson Zil Sesi artist_id=2 bucket_id=1389444597 _size=254851 is_alarm=false date_added=1501406074 date_modified=1501406074 mime_type=audio/mp3 media_type=2 storage_id=65537 is_notification=false album_id=4 bucket_display_name=0
                                             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: files._data (code 2067)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1474)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
                                                 at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertFile(MediaProvider.java:2260)
                                                 at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertInternal(MediaProvider.java:2493)
                                                 at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insert(MediaProvider.java:1892)
                                                 at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:266)
                                                 at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:152)
                                                 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)
```

Comment: why are you `put`-ting `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` twice ?

Comment: sorry. i'm edit now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this answer can help you [SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed when set ringtones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639486/sqliteconstraintexception-error-code-19-constraint-failed-when-set-ringtones)

The value must be unique in the SQL database. The important kind of code in the answer for you is:

```
getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + SDCardRoot + "\"", null);
```